# How to check for the rights of a bot?

Tags: python, discord

I haven't been looking for an answer to this question for a long time, but I closed it and the help on the browser history didn't help in any way. I tried to do it myself, but it didn't work out. I wanted to make it so that if the bot did not have rights, then he wrote about it and if there were, then he did the action, please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Note: This message is written assuming you are using the standard discord.py events and not the bot events, but it obviously also works with the bot events. Just replace "client" with "bot" and instead of "message" use "ctx.message".

You can get your client user via

```py
client.user
```

To get the member object of the client user, you can use

```py
message.channel.guild.get_member(client.user.id)
```

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member)

On member objects you can then call `guild_permissions`

```py
member.guild_permissions
```

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions)

Permission objects are documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions).
Here is an example that sends a message if the bot cannot react to messages.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    client_member = message.channel.guild.get_member(client.user.id)
    if not client_member.guild_permissions.add_reactions:
        await message.channel.send("I cannot add reactions in this channel")
        return
```